# Publish initial pose

Tags: ros, navigation, publish, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a better way to publish the initial pose to AMCL other than creating a publisher and delaying a few seconds before publishing it?  How do I know it got it?  How do I know if AMCL has even started yet?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12655/publish-initial-pose/) by [Dallas Goecker](https://answers.ros.org/users/1654/dallas-goecker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-01-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you just want to make sure that it gets it once it starts, I suggest using a Publisher with a latched topic. That way, whenever `amcl` gets around to subscribing to the `initialpose` topic, as long as your node already has published it, `amcl` should get it.

See the [roscpp](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Publisher_Options) docs for information on how to make a latched publisher in C++.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5